# Which result is being used here?

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading a paper in which I came across the following implication:

Assumptions:

1. $$\frac{d}{d\epsilon} f_{\epsilon} (x) |_{\epsilon = 0} = g(x)$$
2. $$\frac{d}{dt}x(t) = g(x)$$

This apparently implies:
$$x(t) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f^n_{t/n} (\rho)$$

Could someone tell me why? (In the original paper $x$ is a matrix and $f$ is a linear map)

Comment: We might be missing a few elements. Could you give a link to the paper and a page number? In particular, is $\rho$ the initial data for $x$: $x(0) = \rho$?

Comment: We also know that $\phi_{\epsilon}$ varies smoothly with $\epsilon$. The original paper is this https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.2184.pdf. Page number 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me change the notations a little bit. As I understand it, you have an ODE $\dot{x}(t) = A x(t)$ with $A$ a matrix. So the solution is
$$
x(t) = e^{t A} x(0) = (e^{\frac t n A})^n x(0)
$$
for every $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$. You also seem to have some linear maps $F_\varepsilon$ with $F_0 = \mathrm{Id}$ (probably) and $\partial_\varepsilon {F_\varepsilon}_{\rvert \varepsilon = 0} = A$. Hence if everything behaves nicely,
$$
F_\varepsilon = \mathrm{Id} + \varepsilon A + O(\varepsilon^2).
$$
Hence
$$F_{t/n} = \mathrm{Id} + \frac t n A + O(n^{-2})
= e^{\frac t n A} + O(n^{-2}),
$$
which seems to justify your claim.